# C++ define to classes (pattern?)

Tags: c++, design-patterns, c-preprocessor

I have an opensource lib in .c, it has 2 parameters, but they are hardcoded in .h file with #define. They are around all code. 
Change the parameter-> recompile. 
How can I do best design of my cpp wrapper to this to which I can pass some parameter values and will have ability to call code without recompiling it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make them `static` members of a class and initialize them in an implementation file.

```
//header.h
class Hardcoded
{
public:
   static int param;
};

//implementation.cpp
#include "header.h"
int Hardcoded::param = 0;
```

or you could declare a free variable with `extern` which you initialize in an implementation file.

EDIT:

You can continue using macros if you don't want to change the whole code, without requiring compilation every time you want to change the value:

```
#define PARAM Hardcoded::param
```

EDIT:

I now see what you mean:

```
#if QLZ_COMPRESSION_LEVEL == 1
        state->hash[i].offset = 0;
#else
        state->hash_counter[i] = 0;
#endif
```

In this case, it's impossible to do what you want, and you shouldn't do it anyway, because you **need** to compile a different thing every time the define changes. So it's not a matter of re-compiling, it's a matter that **you need to recompile**.

Comment: thanks for good solution! but I can't apply this, hardcoded code is too hardcoded, i think with perfomance optimizations, it has a lot of pieses of code with #if var .... #elif ...#endif, thas't we cant' just  define param to static var. I prefer contribute the wrapper with minimal changes of .c lib code.

Comment: @SeregASM show us some code then... examples where this approach might fail.

Comment: Luchian, Let me show how I solved the problem. I just change defines to all possible values, ans store this to separate .c and .h files and renamed global functions in c file to link that properly to one result file. Next I created cpp wrapper to .c file with classes that is successor of one abstract class. Finally, I have a factory with parameters that create that class I need by giving parameter.